# List from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, list, class

in C# I had the following class:

```
 public class PixelInfo
{
    public DateTime CreatedTime;
    public float x;
    public float y;
}
```

with the following code I was able to save multiple pixels:

```
 private readonly List<PixelInfo> _pixels = new List<PixelInfo>();

foreach...
{
    _pixels.Add(new PixelInfo()
    {
        CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
        x = xx,
        y = yy,
    });
}
```

Now I want to do the same in C++ and I tried it the following way:

```
std::list<PixelInfo> _pixels = {};
_pixels.push_back(new PixelInfo()
{
    ...
});
```

but this gives me an error. How can I save a List of multiple pixels using the class properties?

Comment: new returns a heap allocated memory `pointer`, just use `PixelInfo() { /* code */ }`

Comment: Please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) if you need to program in C++. C++ and C# are *very* different languages.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a C# `List` is not the same as a C++ `std::list`. In C# a list is more like a C++ `std::vector`, and it's `std::vector` that should be the default container to use.

Secondly, in C++ you don't have to use `new` to create objects. In fact, `new` in C++ creates an object somewhere in memory and returns a pointer to it. The result of `new PixelInfo()` will have the type `PixelInfo*` which is quite different from `PixelInfo`.

And thirdly, you can't initialize members of classes or structures in C++ like you do in C#.

I recommend using the [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) function of `std::vector` to create and initialize the objects:

```
std::vector<PixelInfo> _pixels;

// ...

_pixels.emplace_back(some_date_and_time, x, y);
```

Comment: I'd have one more question.

If I do "for (auto pixel : _pixels)" how can i remove the current object from the list in each iteration. using "_pixels.erase(pixel);" doesn't work?

Comment: @nexosharp: use the `erase_if` member function and pass your processing code as a lambda.... the vector will call it for each item, and its return value controls whether to erase or keep the item.